# python list of lists common elements iteration

Tags: python, python-2.7, list, arraylist

```
list= [[5, 4, 6], [6, 4, 5], [7, 1, 2]]
```

I have the above list, I want to compare every list index like `[5,4,6]` with `[6,4,5]` and `[7,1,2]` i.e. with every other list index

and for output: if there exist any common elements between 2 indexes in comparision then I want to output in a format 
"the first element of each index" along with any common elements in the index.

answer for this iteration would be [5,4,6] as 5 is the first element of the index in comparison, 6 is the first element of the index in comparison, 4 is the common element.

next compare `[6, 4, 5]` with `[5,4,6`] and `[7,1,2]` and the answer would be [6,5,4]

next compare `[7,1,2]` with `[5,4,6]` and `[6, 4, 5]` and the answer would be `[7]`

Please help, I have been trying for really long.

basically I want every list index to check for common elements with every other list index and if 2 list indexes have anything in common I want to get a new output list with the first element of both list indexes and common elements

```
final output= [[5,6,4],[6,5,4],[7]]
```

Comment: Can you show what you have tried so far? It doesn't matter if its doesn't work.

Comment: Maybe you should begin with a less complex task. if you don't have an understanding of fundamentals, then you don't want to start with something like this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
myL = [[5, 4, 6], [6, 4, 5], [7, 1, 2]]
newLi = []

for i in range(len(myL)):  
  tmpLi = []
  firstList = myL[i]
  for a in range(len(myL)):
    if a != i:
      secondList = myL[a]
      inCommon = set(firstList).intersection(secondList)
      if len(inCommon) != 0:
        tmpLi.append(firstList[0])
        tmpLi.append(secondList[0])
        for b in inCommon:
          if b not in tmpLi:
            tmpLi.append(b)
  if len(tmpLi) == 0:
    tmpLi.append(firstList[0])
  newLi.append(tmpLi)
print(newLi)
```

Comment: Thankyou for taking the time to answer, i really really appreciate it

line 15: TypeError: 'list' object is not callable

Comment: when i run your answer I get the error TypeError: 'list' object is not callable on line 10

Comment: @sudiksha try replacing `inCommon = list(set(firstList).intersection(secondList))` with `inCommon = set(firstList).intersection(secondList)`